# How to progmatically(Application layer) know both public IP and public port of a tcp connection?

Tags: java, tcp, ip, nat

I am trying to build a java application which will create a tcp connection to 3rd party web server(I don't have access to those servers) like(Facebook, Wikipedia etc).

Is there any way where I will be able to pragmatically know the *** both public IP and public port *** that is used to connect to these websites from my java application?

NB: Any information or idea on how ISP/Mobile operators assign these public IP/port to the users in their private network will also be very very useful.

Comment: You definitely can't get back the public port, as that will change on each distinct connection.  There are a number of sites where you can get the public IP, such as https://www.whatismyip.com/ (no affiliation, just the first one on Google).

Comment: @JoeC I need the public port. Otherwise I could use my own tcp server server to connect and know the public IP. Is there any way to know or guess the public port was used to create that tcp connection(connection to Wikipedia).

Comment: Why do you think you need the public port?  It's literally assigned at random.